# Express Doesn't Display Json data

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I am new in node js and i am Facing the error.
fb-downloader package is working fine with console.log()
But i want to display results on webpage. But the Express displays only `{}`
Please Help me.

```
const getFBInfo = require("fb-downloader");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3016;

app.get("/",function(req, res){
        data = getFBInfo("https://www.facebook.com/watch?v=272591278381388");
        res.json(data);
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port http://localhost:${port}!`)
});
```

Sorry for Bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getFBInfo` is an *asynchronous* operation, therefore use `async` and `await`:

```js
app.get("/",async function(req, res){
  var data = await getFBInfo("https://www.facebook.com/watch?v=272591278381388");
  res.json(data);
});
```